# Cannot remove duplicates properly

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed, hosts

I am new to shell scripting and I was trying to write a small script to download and parse hosts files.

```
cd /tmp

rm hosts*

#Download files
aria2c -j 10 http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.txt -o hostsA
aria2c -j 10 "http://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/serverlist.php?hostformat=hosts&showintro=0&mimetype=plaintext" -o hostsB

#Parse files
sed 's/0.0.0.0/127.0.0.1/' hostsA>  hostsM
sed -n '/^127.0.0.1/p' hostsB  >> hostsM  

#Remove duplicates
awk '!x[$0]++' hostsM > hosts

#mv /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.backup
#mv hosts.txt /etc/hosts

echo "Complete."
```

For example, the following entry is occurring twice:

```
127.0.0.1 newopenx.detik.com
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/szcpotob5i57e2k/hosts?dl=0)'s the complete hosts fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change your awk to `awk '!x[$1]++' hostsM > hosts`

Comment: This didn't work either. All lines are starting with `127.0.0.1 ` so this shouldn't matter, should it?

Comment: Ok then place your `hosts` file in question.

Comment: Added a dropbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your awk to this:

```
awk '{sub(/\r/, "")} !x[$0]++' hostsM > hosts
```

As some lines in your original hosts file have trailing `\r` before `\n` (e.g. `DOS EOL`).

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that webservers prefer `\r\n` instead of `\n`. Phew.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind sorting, the `-u` option of `sort` removes duplicates. Mnemonic: unique.

```
sort -u hostsM >hosts
```

Your previous line is duplicating every line that starts with 127.0.0.1. If you just want to preserve those and throw away the others, use the -n option:

```
sed -n '/^127.0.0.1/p' hostsB >>hostsM
```

Comment: I initially was using the `-n` option. I am not much familiar with `sed` and reading it's man page, I didn't realize the quiet output meant this. Also, I was hoping for a non-sort solution. The complexity is `O(nlogn)` (in fact it wll be k*n*ln(n) + n) instead of the `O(n)`. With `n` being very large (no of entries) sort isn't optimal.